# 'url/to/your/fork' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, github

im so beginner in git and gihub and just need to start Using it to Save my Work , so i start with :

```
git status
```

```
git checkout -b feature/starter-code
```

```
git add -A
```

```
git commit -m "add starter code"
```

so till now all is working fine till i start to

git pull origin main

then it shows me this ;
fatal: 'url/to/your/fork' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

after git origin main i suppose to

```
git push origin feature/starter-code
```

please help

i tried too many commands but couldn't push feature/starter-code yo github

Comment: Did you actually *create* a fork on GitHub first? What command did you use to create the *local* repository on your own computer (your laptop or other local machine)? As you're new to both Git and GitHub, a lot of terms will be new to you, and Git itself is confusing enough without adding GitHub to the mix, but see also [ask]: it is hard to tell from your question exactly what you did to get *into* this situation in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the right remote set?

In your `.git` directory you can find the file `config` which should have something similar to

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:GITHUB_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If that is not present you need to run something like

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:GITHUB_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO.git
```

To add the origin remote.

After that you should be able to git push / pull.

Comment: error: remote origin already exists. this is what i get

Comment: I think you have put "/urlto/your/fork" in the remote, but that should be the *actual* URL of your fork